# OnConnectionAsync method issues when launching .NET Core apps on OS X

Tags: .net-core, model-view-controller, kestrel

For some odd reason I cannot launch any web app projects on OS X.
The application starts as expected with this output.

```
Using launch settings from /Users/erik/Development/DotNetProjects/Funka/Funka/Properties/launchSettings.json...
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /Users/erik/Development/DotNetProjects/Funka/Funka
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

As first request is passed to any of the addresses above I get this stacktrace, and I cannot figure out why since the project is just created, no modifications is done to the code.

Error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Uncaught exception from the OnConnectionAsync method of an IConnectionAdapter.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: Internal error
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsServerAsync>b__51_0(SslServerAuthenticationOptions arg1, CancellationToken arg2, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync[TArg1,TArg2](Func`5 beginMethod, Action`1 endMethod, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, Object state)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(SslServerAuthenticationOptions sslServerAuthenticationOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionAdapter.InnerOnConnectionAsync(ConnectionAdapterContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ApplyConnectionAdaptersAsync()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `dotnet dev-certs https —-trust`, which will trust the local cert, or generate one if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few `dotnet` CLI commands that fixed my issue.

I had to remove the existing cert and then generate a new one, like so:

```
$ sudo dotnet dev-certs https --clean
$ dotnet dev-certs https
```

Source from comment on GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/31749#issuecomment-423694193).